# error when I use jsonpath(python version)

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I am trying to extract some info from a list of json files, and I use jsonfiles, it worked well when I extract from a single json file, however when I use for a list of files, it returns False, and all False!!! Here are code

```
json_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset_demo/results"
os.chdir(json_path)

for file_json in os.listdir(json_path):
  if file_json.endswith('.json'):
    nums_comment = jsonpath(file_json, '$.node.edge_media_to_comment[*]')
    nums_likes = jsonpath(file_json, '$.node.edge_media_preview_like[*]')
    print(nums_comment,nums_likes)
```

and it ruturned

```
False False
False False
False False
False False
```

the number of json files is right, but the result are wrong

Comment: There is no built-in `jsonpath` function and you're not showing where you import yours from, so it's hard to help. You should also show the working version.

Comment: I worked it out, I forget use open and the file is empty, a stupied mistake. Thanks for your warmheart!